# Python write multiple numpy array to csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to add features of multiple images by converting them from raw data format to .csv.

I have read and displayed features of two images via print function but during addition of contents to csv, i am only able to add single numpy array. I want to add few thousand images in same csv.

Below is printed output, but csv only shows one array (having features of single image).

[Image showing code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAjEi.png)

Comment: All `csv` is  is rows with a consistent number of columns and delimiters, a simple 2d table.  How are multiple images supposed to be represented in that format?  Images are 2 or even 3d (rgb).  An array of 1000s of the same size would be 4d.  That's not consistent with the 2d csv layout.

Comment: On the next stage I will flat the array of image and apply classification. The final version of csv contain in first column "id of image" in header row and remaining rows will contain "flat features" of that image. Next column contain "id of 2nd image" and its rows will be features of that 2nd image, and so on.

Comment: I have done this by using following code: with open("output.csv", "a") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data_read[2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by using following code: 
 `with open("output.csv", "a") as f: 
writer = csv.writer(f) 
writer.writerows(data_read[2])`